# How do I initialize a struct of typedef'd unions in C?

Tags: c, initialization, c89

So if I have code such as the following:

```
typedef union {
  long integer;
  float decimal;
  long *integerPtr;
  float *decimalPtr;
} Number;

typedef struct Point {
  Number x;
  Number y;
} Point;
```

How do I initialize this? Is it as simple as the following? Can I do this with a const as well?

```
Point p = { 100, 100 };
const Point p2 = { 640, 200 };

int someNum, someOtherNum;

Point p3 = { &someNum, &someOtherNum };
```

FYI: I am specifically targeting pre C99 C code.

Comment: Add the tag for the version of C you target. In general, you should not write ancient C code, but use modern C which started with C99. It supports designated initialisers which allow to initialise `union`s not only to the first member. Re. your question: it is not clear how you want to initialise the `union`s. And what do you mean with "Can I do this with a const as well?"? How is your code supposed to know which union-member is currently active?

Comment: Is `Point p = { {100}, {100} };` sufficient for you?  It initializes the `integer` fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are specifically targetting *old* compilers, you will only be able to initialize the first element of the union. The nice part will be that you will not be bothered by the *strict aliasing rule*. Long story made short, here is what will happen:

- initialize with integer values: all is fine the litteral or variables will be converted to long, so this will work fine:

  ```
  Point p = { 100, 100 };
  const Point p2 = { 640, 200 };
  ```
- initialize with pointers: the long field will receive the value of the pointer converted to a long. What actually happens is unspecified, but on little endian common architecture if long is greater that pointer or on any architecture where long has same size as a pointer and where the representation of a pointer is its integer address, all will be fine. In fact you initialize the long value but as the pointer representation as same representation as the long, you get the expected result. So here again this works as expected (on a common architecture):

  ```
  int someNum, someOtherNum;
  Point p3 = { &someNum, &someOtherNum };
  ```
- initialize with floats: no direct way because to conversion of a float to a long has **not** the same representation as a long. But as strict aliasing rule does not apply you can try to use type punning, provide the size of a long is the same as the size of a float:

  ```
  float f=12.5, g=1.;
  Point p4 = { *((long *) &f), *((long *) &g) };
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Nice concise answer.